# Does the single season of Flash Forward manage to finish up plot points?

Tags: production, flash-forward

Did the production team get a chance to wrap up the Story arcs or were there major plot point left unfinished that they intended to finish in subsequent seasons?

Comment: @Valamas a related question on SciFi that may be of interest: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2578/what-would-have-happened-in-the-second-season-of-flashforward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only were their major plot points left unfinished, but in classic cliffhanger style, a whole new one opened up at the end. Through the season we mostly found out who and what caused the blackout, but not *why* everyone flash-forwarded. We never found out the end goal of the men behind the blackout.